# How to use integrated support for dyndns clients in 2Wire router?

Tags: router, dynamic-dns

I logged into the 2Wire web interface, and get to "Broadband Link Advanced Settings" page, how do I use it's integrated support for dyndns clients ?

Under "Broadband DNS" it has "Obtain DNS information automatically" selected, under that :

```
Manually configure your DNS information: 
 Primary Server:    
 Secondary Server:  

 Domain Name:
```

what do I need to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2wire Residential Gateway does not support dynamic DNS.  2wire has a [support article](http://support.2wire.com/?page=view&article=89&text=&cat=&sort=) about dynamic DNS which states:

> Dynamic DNS works with a 2Wire
>   Residential Gateway as long as a
>   computer on the internal network is
>   running a dynamic DNS client.

So you must run the dynamic DNS client on your computer, not on the router.  The setting you are showing are to configure the DNS servers that are used to resolve hostnames on your network, not to configure dynamic DNS.